# Why char 0x80 == 0xFFFFFF80?

Tags: data-type

As far as I know a char is an 8 bit variable

[image: char 0x80 == 0xFFFFFF80]

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  char x = 0x80;
  if(x != 0x80){
    Serial.println(x, HEX);
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To illustrate the reasons better let's look at the actual content of the data.

`0x80` is `0b10000000` in binary. A `char` is a *signed* variable, which means that the most significant bit is the sign bit, with *two's complement* representation

So in 8-bit signed representation the value `0b10000000` is a sign bit and zero value - which is -128 in decimal notation, which is "-128 + the 7 least significant bits", or -128 + 0 in this case.

When you print a signed value on the Arduino as HEX there is no 8-bit specific function for it. Neither is there a 16 bit function. However there is a 32-bit signed function, which is the closest match available. So the compiler performs *type promotion* to 32-bit signed, then represent it as hexadecimal.

Now -128 in signed 32-bit is calculated in the same way - take the value of the most significant bit, negate it, and add the value of all the other bits to it.  With 32-bits the value of the most significant bit, in decimal, is 2147483648, so negate that into -2147483648. Now we need to make that into -128, so we need the difference between the two to add to it. That's 2147483520.

So you get the MSB + 2147483520, which in hexadecimal, is 0xFFFFFF80.

Of course, the compiler doesn't go through that whole routine - instead it uses something called *sign extension*. This method basically means copying the sign bit from the original smaller (char) type into every bit to the left of it in the larger type:

```
                           10000000 8 bit signed
                  11111111 10000000 16 bit signed
11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000 32 bit signed
```

All those are -128 in two's complement, just stored in different size variables. So when you come to print it, that is just what you get - the two's complement representation of -128 in the variable size that has been accepted by the print function.

You might find [this site](http://www.binaryconvert.com/) useful for experimentation and furthering your understanding of variable data storage.

Answer (score 2):

Sign extension. Try this:

```
void loop() {
  char x = 0x80;
  if(x != (char) 0x80){
    Serial.println(x, HEX);
  }
```

Before any operation involving different types, the lower ones must be promoted to higher ones.

The constant 0x80 is an integer value, so `x` must be promoted to `int` before the test. The first bit of an `int` value is the sign bit. Sign bit is extended (copied to the left side bits). So `x` become 0xFFFFF80 and then you compare it against 0x0000080.

Every time you put a *char* where an *int* is excepted the same thing happen.

See? Programming is hard, programming in C is harder, programming in C++ is the hardest.

C is full of traps.

Answer (score 2):

char is signed so `0x80` is really `-0x80` (`==-128`). When promoted to a higher width the sign gets copied into the new bits `0xffffff80` (still `==-128`).

if you put unsigned in front of char you won't get that issue (though may encounter others).

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned char x = 0x80;
  if(x != 0x80){
    Serial.println(x, HEX);
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```